# FlexSlider - slideshow from left to right

Tags: animation, slideshow, flexslider

I am using flexslider and it's work fine.  But how can I change slideshow to "left to right"?  There's only 2 animation: fade and slide (from right to left).  Please, help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new property called 'reverse' that works in version 1.8. If you set it to true, the slider will animate left to right.

Read About the Properties:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

Download v1.8:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/downloads